# VBA Excel code to save picture as PNG to file location

Tags: excel, vba

I tried different codes but I cant go with the correct output. I want to have a code that I can choose a file location. All working, I just need to save the PNG to file location selected when saving. I only got the following:

```
FName = "C:\Users\Desktop\Nutrifacts and Analysis-Save\1.png"

Sub picsave_Click()

Dim pic_rng As Range
Dim ShTemp As Worksheet
Dim ChTemp As Chart
Dim PicTemp As Picture
Dim FName As String


FName = "C:\Users\Desktop\Nutrifacts and Analysis-Save\1.png"



Application.ScreenUpdating = False

ThisWorkbook.Windows(1).DisplayGridlines = False

Set pic_rng = Worksheets(1).Range("A1:R31")
Set ShTemp = Worksheets.Add
Charts.Add
ActiveChart.Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:=ShTemp.Name
Set ChTemp = ActiveChart
pic_rng.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture

 With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
 ActiveSheet.Shapes.Item(1).Line.Visible = msoFalse
 ActiveSheet.Shapes.Item(1).Width = .Range("A1:R31").Width
 ActiveSheet.Shapes.Item(1).Height = .Range("A1:R31").Height
End With

ChTemp.Paste
ChTemp.Export fileName:=FName, Filtername:="png"

  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
  ShTemp.Delete
 Application.DisplayAlerts = True

 ThisWorkbook.Windows(1).DisplayGridlines = True

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Set ShTemp = Nothing
Set ChTemp = Nothing
Set PicTemp = Nothing



MsgBox ("Done.")

   End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below. Added `varResult` variable to get the filename. You may change it as you want. Used `Application.GetSaveAsFilename` to get the file name.

```
Sub test()

Dim pic_rng As Range
Dim ShTemp As Worksheet
Dim ChTemp As Chart
Dim PicTemp As Picture
Dim FName As String
Dim varResult As Variant

On Error Resume Next
FName = "C:\Users\Desktop\Nutrifacts and Analysis-Save\1.png"

'displays the save file dialog
varResult = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(FileFilter:="PNG (*.png), *.png")
If varResult = False Then
  Exit Sub ' do what you want
Else
  FName = varResult
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

ThisWorkbook.Windows(1).DisplayGridlines = False

Set pic_rng = Worksheets(1).Range("A1:R31")
Set ShTemp = Worksheets.Add
Charts.Add
ActiveChart.Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:=ShTemp.Name
Set ChTemp = ActiveChart
pic_rng.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
     ActiveSheet.Shapes.Item(1).Line.Visible = msoFalse
     ActiveSheet.Shapes.Item(1).Width = .Range("A1:R31").Width
     ActiveSheet.Shapes.Item(1).Height = .Range("A1:R31").Height
End With


ChTemp.Paste
ChTemp.Export Filename:=FName, Filtername:="png"

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ShTemp.Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

ThisWorkbook.Windows(1).DisplayGridlines = True

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Set ShTemp = Nothing
Set ChTemp = Nothing
Set PicTemp = Nothing

MsgBox ("Done.")

End Sub
```